# How to find boost runtime version

Tags: c++, boost

I am writing a C++ library that uses boost.

In this library I want to include information about the boost version that was used to compile the binary version of my library.
I can use the macro `BOOST_VERSION` and this is fine.

I also wanted to determine which is the runtime version of boost so I could compare with the boost version that was used to compile my library. Obviously I cannot use the macro because it will give me the hard coded version at compile time, not at runtime.

What I needed is a function in boost (like `boost::get_version()`). Is there a way to do this in boost?

Comment: why do you need the version at runtime? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am using boost-python to wrap a c++ library to python.
I want to make a function in my library that does a complete report of the user installation.
When a problem occurs I can ask the user to send me the result of executing something like:
`$ python -c "import mylib; print mylib.info()"` to get complete information about their installation

Answer (score 5):

You can use the macro to create some code as follows:

```
std::cout << "Using Boost "     
          << BOOST_VERSION / 100000     << "."  // maj. version
          << BOOST_VERSION / 100 % 1000 << "."  // min. version
          << BOOST_VERSION % 100                // patch version
          << std::endl;
```

This works on boost 1.51.x and upwards.  Not sure if this is what you are looking for though, I will keep going and see if there is a way to get it from the currently loaded dll in a more elegant way.

## Addendum:

To find run-time versions:

After looking at the Boost system, it seems that the simplest way you could do what you are looking for would be to have platform dependant code which is utilised at compiletime to make the different versions of executable.

### For Windows:

You will need to query the DLL for its version using [GetFileVersionInfoEx API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969434%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [GetFileVersionInfo API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647003%28VS.85%29.aspx), you also need to take into account if the OS is 32 bit or 64 bit, so here is some code which may be of use:

```
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS) (HANDLE, PBOOL);
LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS IsWow64ProcessFunc;

BOOL is64BitOS()
{
    BOOL retval= FALSE;
    // need to check if the OS is 64 bit, and we cant therefore indiscrimately call the 64 bit function for this, so we use the following:
    IsWow64ProcessFunc= (LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32")),"IsWow64Process");

    if(IsWow64ProcessFunc != NULL)
    {
        if (!IsWow64ProcessFunc(GetCurrentProcess(),&bIsWow64))
        {
            // your error handling code in here
        }
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Then we can utilise a straight-forward bit of code to get the version of the DLL:

```
void myWindowsDLLVersionChecker()
{
    DWORD  versionHandle = NULL;
    UINT   size      = 0;
    LPBYTE buffer  = NULL;
    DWORD  versionSize   = GetFileVersionInfoSize( szVersionFile, &versionHandle);

    if (verSize != NULL)
    {
        LPSTR versionData = new char[versionSize];

        if (GetFileVersionInfo( szVersionFile, versionHandle, versionSize, versionData))
        {
            if (VerQueryValue(versionData,"\\",(VOID FAR* FAR*)&buffer,&size))
            {
                if (size)
                {
                    VS_FIXEDFILEINFO *versionInfo = (VS_FIXEDFILEINFO *)buffer;
                    if (versionInfo->dwSignature == 0xFEEF04BD)  // value from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646997(v=vs.85).aspx
                    {
                        if(is64BitOS())    //  if it is true then its a 64 bit Windows OS
                        {
                                major =     (versionInfo->dwProductVersionMS >> 16) & 0xff;
                                minor =     (versionInfo->dwProductVersionMS >>  0) & 0xff;
                                revision =  (versionInfo->dwProductVersionLS >> 16) & 0xff;
                                build =     (versionInfo->dwProductVersionLS >>  0) & 0xff;
                        } 
                        else //  32 bit Windows OS
                        {
                                major =     HIWORD(versionInfo->dwProductVersionMS);
                                minor =     LOWORD(versionInfo->dwProductVersionMS);
                                revision =  HIWORD(versionInfo->dwProductVersionLS);
                                build =     LOWORD(versionInfo->dwProductVersionLS);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        delete[] versionData;
    }
}
```

### For Linux:

Horribly cant remember the code for that at present, however here is a partial solution from memory (I don't have a Linux machine to hand at the moment, will check this in more detail later, but should work with only minor modifications at most).

```
void myLinuxDLLVersionChecker() 
{
    // call readelf as an external proces son libboost_system.so, 
    // and use the information returned to extract the version from.
    // or use something like
    setenv("LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS", "1", 1);
    FILE *ldd = popen("/lib/libboost_system.so");
    //  information from http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld.so
    // the above pretty much replicates ldd's output, so you can pick out the version
}
```

### Combining the two:

To make the same thing happen in multiple OSes you would probably have to use something like:

```
#ifdef __unix__                    /* __unix__ is usually defined by compilers targeting Unix systems */
void detectBoostDllVersion()  // does not have to be void, can be whatever you need
{
    myLinuxDLLVersionChecker();
}
#elif defined(_WIN32) || defined(WIN32)     /* _Win32 is usually defined by compilers targeting 32 or   64 bit Windows systems */
void detectBoostDllVersion()  // has to match the same return type as the previous version
{
    myWindowsDLLVersionChecker();
}
#endif
```

Now dependant upon which OS this is compiled for, the right function will be pointed at by the `detectBoostDLLVersion()` function :)

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing to get the _boost compile-time version_.
Now i wanted something for the _boost run-time version_.
Thanks for investigating.

Comment: there we go, have added example code for windows and linux, you can extend the principle to support multiple other targets such as `__arm__` etc

Comment: let me know how this works for you, or if you need any more information:)

Comment: Definitively seems the only way to go. It is horribly complicated, though. Just to get a version number. Thanks a lot for your investigation. It could be generalized to access version numbers of any libraries.
I think I will make a feature request in boost library. Let's see what they say.

Comment: Yeah I agree, not a very elegant way to get to a version number.  If it would help let me know the details of the feature request and I can try and back it too (although its not a feature I have needed in the past I definitely think it should be easier than it is to find) strength in numbers :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feature in boost and I think you can only scan binary file for this thing (`ldd` in linux for example).

Comment: I wanted the solution to be cross-platform, if possible.