# Get list of alive IP on network (Linux)

Tags: c++, linux

I Have this nice small program which gives me a vector of all alive ip on the network to which system is connected...but works only on windows

```
std::vector<std::string> resultIPList;
PMIB_IPNET_TABLE2 pipTable = NULL;
unsigned long status = GetIpNetTable2(AF_INET, &pipTable);
if(status != NO_ERROR)
{
    LOG_ERROR("Error in getting ip Table")
    return resultIPList;
}
for(unsigned i = 0; i < pipTable->NumEntries; i++)
{
    char* ip = inet_ntoa(pipTable->Table[i].Address.Ipv4.sin_addr);
    std::string str = std::string(ip);
    resultIPList.push_back(str);
}
FreeMibTable(pipTable);
pipTable = NULL;
return resultIPList;
```

is there any way i can do same in Linux (Replacement of GetIpNetTable Function). i am using RHEL

Comment: I'd take a look at the netstat source for your Linux Distribution.

Comment: This may be a question for http://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [rtnetlink](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html) and [getifaddrs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html)  on RHEL there is also the [NetworkManager](https://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/developers/api/09/spec.html) all three should allow what you are looking for but I don't think either of the three is a direct replacement for the windows specific API.  You will also have to have some way to crach your code so that the relevant functions are compiled.  I normally use `#ifndef' to split the code out, that way you can have the same code returning the same things but utilising different code bodies dependant upon the target OS you are compiling for.

I recently answered another question where windows/linux compilation was an issue (for finding the runtime version of boost) [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20140321/how-to-find-boost-runtime-version/20141243#20141243), the principle remains the same and can easily be tailored to your needs.

As an aside I suspect that [Boost.Asio](http://think-async.com/Asio) may help you out too for a single point of call in both Windows and Linux. You can also get it as an [integrated-with-Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) version or as [standalone](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.10.1/doc/) to achieve a smaller footprint.

Let me know how you get on, or if you need any more information :)

### Addendum

On Linux you could use something along the lines of:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void
print_sockaddr(struct sockaddr* addr,const char *name)
{
    char addrbuf[128] ;

    addrbuf[0] = 0;
    if(addr->sa_family == AF_UNSPEC)
        return;
    switch(addr->sa_family) {
        case AF_INET:
            inet_ntop(addr->sa_family,&((struct sockaddr_in*)addr)->sin_addr,addrbuf,sizeof(addrbuf));
            break;
        case AF_INET6:
            inet_ntop(addr->sa_family,&((struct sockaddr_in6*)addr)->sin6_addr,addrbuf,sizeof(addrbuf));
            break;
        default:
            sprintf(addrbuf,"Unknown (%d)",(int)addr->sa_family);
            break;

    }
    printf("%-16s %s\n",name,addrbuf);
}

void
print_ifaddr(struct ifaddrs *addr)
{
    char addrbuf[128] ;

    addrbuf[0] = 0;
    printf("%-24s %s\n","Interface Name:",addr->ifa_name);
    if(addr->ifa_addr != NULL)
        print_sockaddr(addr->ifa_addr,"Interface Address:");
    if(addr->ifa_netmask != NULL)
        print_sockaddr(addr->ifa_netmask,"Netmask:");
    if(addr->ifa_broadaddr != NULL)
        print_sockaddr(addr->ifa_broadaddr,"Broadcast address:");
    if(addr->ifa_dstaddr != NULL)
        print_sockaddr(addr->ifa_dstaddr,"Peer address:");
    puts("");
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    struct ifaddrs *addrs,*tmp;

    if(getifaddrs(&addrs) != 0) {
        perror("getifaddrs");
        return 1;
    }
    for(tmp = addrs; tmp ; tmp = tmp->ifa_next) {
        print_ifaddr(tmp);
    }

    freeifaddrs(addrs);

    return 0;
}
```

For other derivatives (Unix, BSD etc) this more basic set of code may be more usefult, though I vaguely remember some problems under BSD (Sorry cant remember what exactly at the moment, think its to do with fail scenarios where certain conditions will render it non-operational)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define INT_TO_ADDR(_addr) \
(_addr & 0xFF), \
(_addr >> 8 & 0xFF), \
(_addr >> 16 & 0xFF), \
(_addr >> 24 & 0xFF)

int main()
{
    struct ifconf ifc;
    struct ifreq ifr[10];
    int sd, ifc_num, addr, bcast, mask, network, i;

    // Create a socket then use ioctl on the file descriptor to retrieve the interface information.

    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sd > 0)
    {
        ifc.ifc_len = sizeof(ifr);
        ifc.ifc_ifcu.ifcu_buf = (caddr_t)ifr;

        if (ioctl(sd, SIOCGIFCONF, &ifc) == 0)
        {
            ifc_num = ifc.ifc_len / sizeof(struct ifreq);
            printf("%d interfaces found.\n", ifc_num);

            for (i = 0; i < ifc_num; ++i)
            {
                if (ifr[i].ifr_addr.sa_family != AF_INET)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                /* display the interface name */
                printf("%d) Interface Name: %s\n", i+1, ifr[i].ifr_name);

                /* Retrieve the IP address, broadcast address, and subnet mask. */
                if (ioctl(sd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr[i]) == 0)
                {
                    addr = ((struct sockaddr_in *)(&ifr[i].ifr_addr))->sin_addr.s_addr;
                    printf("%d) Interface address: %d.%d.%d.%d\n", i+1, INT_TO_ADDR(addr));
                }
                if (ioctl(sd, SIOCGIFBRDADDR, &ifr[i]) == 0)
                {
                    bcast = ((struct sockaddr_in *)(&ifr[i].ifr_broadaddr))->sin_addr.s_addr;
                    printf("%d) Broadcast: %d.%d.%d.%d\n", i+1, INT_TO_ADDR(bcast));
                }
                if (ioctl(sd, SIOCGIFNETMASK, &ifr[i]) == 0)
                {
                    mask = ((struct sockaddr_in *)(&ifr[i].ifr_netmask))->sin_addr.s_addr;
                    printf("%d) Netmask: %d.%d.%d.%d\n", i+1, INT_TO_ADDR(mask));
                }                

                /* Compute the current network value from the address and netmask. */
                network = addr & mask;
                printf("%d) Current Network: %d.%d.%d.%d\n", i+1, INT_TO_ADDR(network));
            }                      
        }

        close(sd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously you would need to tailor the code to suit your needs, but perhaps this will help a bit:)

Comment: Please do no change the code, the code above is exactly as I use, and does not require extra includes.  Cheers:)

Answer (score 0):

[getifaddrs](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getifaddrs) FTW

```
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <cstdlib>

ifaddrs* pAdapter = NULL;
ifaddrs* pList = NULL;

int result = getifaddrs(&pList);

if (result == -1)
   return;

pAdapter = pList;
while (pAdapter)
{
    if ((pAdapter->ifa_addr != NULL) && (pAdapter->ifa_flags & IFF_UP))
    {
        if (pAdapter->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET)
        {
            sockaddr_in* addr = (sockaddr_in*)(pAdapter->ifa_addr);
        }
        else if (pAdapter->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET6)
        {
            sockaddr_in6* addr6 = (sockaddr_in6*)(pAdapter->ifa_addr);
        }
    }
    pAdapter = pAdapter->ifa_next;
}
freeifaddrs(pList);
pList = NULL;
```